# How to interpret coefficients in a Poisson regression?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, poisson-distribution, regression-coefficients

How can I interpret the main effects (coefficients for dummy-coded factor) in a Poisson regression?

Assume the following example:

```r
treatment     <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), 
                        levels = c(1, 2),
                        labels = c("placebo", "treated"))
improved      <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)),
                        levels = c(1, 2, 3),
                        labels = c("none", "some", "marked"))    
numberofdrugs <- rpois(84, 10) + 1    
healthvalue   <- rpois(84, 5)   
y             <- data.frame(healthvalue, numberofdrugs, treatment, improved)
test          <- glm(healthvalue ~ numberofdrugs + treatment + 
                     improved, y, family=poisson)
summary(test)
```

The output is:

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       1.88955    0.19243   9.819   <2e-16 ***
numberofdrugs    -0.02303    0.01624  -1.418    0.156    
treatmenttreated -0.01271    0.10861  -0.117    0.907   MAIN EFFECT  
improvedsome     -0.13541    0.14674  -0.923    0.356   MAIN EFFECT 
improvedmarke    -0.10839    0.12212  -0.888    0.375   MAIN EFFECT 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I know that the incident rate for `numberofdrugs` is `exp(-0.023)=0.977`. But how do I interpret the main effects for the dummy variables?

Comment: A similar answer (but framed more mathematically) can be found here: [How to interpret parameter estimates in Poisson GLM results](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/128926/).

Comment: It's interesting that the referenced question was closed as off-topic. (I wouldn't have agreed that it was off-topic, since any answer would also apply to the output of any stats program that returned a table of coefficients to the user, and do agree with you that it's close-worthy on the basis of being a duplicate.) It seems to me that the SO community is too "tight" on questions that ask for interpretation of output from R. They are not really on-topic for StackOverflow since there is no suggestion that coding help is needed.

Comment: @DWin, I don't think interpreting statistical output is off topic on [stats.SE]. I voted to close that question as a duplicate of this. Others seem to have voted OT, I gather, because it seemed to them that the OP "dump[ed their] computer output there and [hoped someone would] run the stat analysis for [them]".

Comment: @gung: I was clear that it wasn't you that was calling it OT. Your comments were clear on that point. (I thought I was agreeing with you.) The "reason" listed on a close vote is often a majority or plurality decision.

Comment: Relevant:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353

Answer (score 73):

The exponentiated `numberofdrugs` coefficient is the multiplicative term to use for the goal of calculating the estimated `healthvalue` when `numberofdrugs` increases by 1 unit. In the case of categorical (factor) variables, the exponentiated coefficient is the multiplicative term relative to the base (first factor) level for that variable (since R uses treatment contrasts by default). The `exp(Intercept)` is the baseline rate, and all other estimates would be relative to it.

In your example the estimated `healthvalue` for someone with `2` drugs, `"placebo"` and `improvement=="none"` would be (using addition inside exp as the equivalent of multiplication):

```
 exp( 1.88955 +    # thats the baseline contribution
      2*-0.02303 + 0 + 0 )  # and estimated value will be somewhat lower
 [1] 6.318552
```

While someone on `4` drugs, `"treated"`, and `"some"` improvement would have an estimated `healthvalue` of

```
exp( 1.88955 + 4*-0.02303 + -0.01271 + -0.13541)
[1] 5.203388
```

ADDENDUM: This is what it means to be "additive on the log scale". "Additive on the log-odds scale" was the phrase that my teacher, Barbara McKnight, used when emphasizing the need to use all applicable term values times their estimated coefficients when doing any kind of prediction. This was in discussions of interpreting logistic regression coefficients, but Poisson regression is similar if you use an offset of time at risk to get rates. You add first all the coefficients (including the intercept term) times eachcovariate values and then exponentiate the resulting sum. The way to return coefficients from regression objects in R is generally to use the `coef()` extractor function (done with a different random realization below):

```
 coef(test)
  #   (Intercept)    numberofdrugs treatmenttreated     improvedsome   improvedmarked 
  #   1.18561313       0.03272109       0.05544510      -0.09295549       0.06248684
```

So the calculation of the estimate for a subject with `4` drugs, `"treated"`, with `"some"` improvement would be:

```
 exp( sum( coef(test)[ c(1,2,3,4) ]* c(1,4,1,1) ) ) 
 [1] 3.592999
```

And the linear predictor for that case should be the sum of:

```
 coef(test)[c(1,2,3,4)]*c(1,4,1,1) 
 #    (Intercept)    numberofdrugs treatmenttreated     improvedsome 
 #     1.18561313       0.13088438       0.05544510      -0.09295549
```

These principles should apply to any stats package that returns a table of coefficients to the user. The method and principles is more general than might appear from my use of R.

---

I'm copying selected clarifying comments since they 'disappear' in the default display:

> Q: So you interpret the coefficients as ratios! Thank you! – MarkDollar

A: The coefficients are the natural_logarithms of the ratios. – DWin

> Q2: In that case, in a poisson regression, are the exponentiated coefficients also referred to as "odds ratios"? – oort

A2: No. If it were logistic regression they would be but in Poisson regression, where the LHS is number of events and the implicit denominator is the number at risk, then the exponentiated coefficients are "rate ratios" or "relative risks".

Comment: So it let you vote twice? How nice. I thought offering an R code implementation of the interpretation might rescue it from the forces of classification rectitude. The OP composed a nice self contained example. Maybe I should have demonstrated an extractor function, so I think I will.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted your response on SO, then it moved here and I upvoted again :)

Comment: Thanks so far! I know the realtion between the dummies and cavariables, but I'm just interested of how to interpret the Main effects (I marked them). Is it possible to take teh incidient rate from a Main effects, for example for the dummy treated 'exp(-0.012)=0.99' and interpret it as the rate from which the healtvalue decreases, when switching from reference category to treated? It must be, no?

Comment: The exponentiated coefficients are always interpreted as ratios. Ratios of 'what' to 'what' depends on the units of analysis. 'Rates' are different, having an implicit number and time value. So if you are willing to change your terminology, then perhaps,'yes". Best answers come from describing the analysis situation fully.

Comment: Ah ok this is what I wanted to know. So you interpret the coefficients as ratios! Thank you!

Comment: The coefficients are the _natural_logarithms_ of the ratios.

Comment: In that case, in a poisson regression, are the exponentiated coefficients also referred to as "odds ratios"?

Comment: No. If it were logistic regression they would be but in Poisson regression where the LHS is number of events and the implicit denominator is the number at risk, then the exponentiated coefficients are "rate ratios" or "relative risks".

Comment: exp( 1.88955 + 4*-0.02303 + -0.01271 + -0.13541) = 5.203388 not 38.44813. Or have I got it wrong?

Comment: You're right about what my machine returns. I will need to look at this further. I'm not sure where that value of 38 came from. The maximum value of "healthvalue" in the dataset was 9. I think the explanation remains correct.